# Can the word "iso" be used if the quantities are zero in number?

Tags: isotope

Both $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{He^2+}$ ions have zero electrons. So can we call them isoelectronic species?

And if two species have a difference in the number of protons and neutrons equal to zero, can we call them isodiaphers?

Finally, I know that only hydrogen has zero neutrons. But if there was any other element with zero neutrons, could we call hydrogen and that element isotones?

Comment: The notorious example is the zero isotherm in context of meteorology and Celsius temperature scale. Quantities with zero value difference are considered the same ( isos = the same ). Quantities themselves, or objects with them as an attribute,  form respectively named isosets, isolines or isosurfaces. It is valid even for cases when quantities themselves have zero value.

Comment: (cont.) but for particular cases, zero values may lead to trivial, formally defined  but unused isoset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for the reasons everyone else said.

“Iso-” establishes an equivalence class. When that’s based on the number of something, 0 is a number, and all the equivalence relations such as the transitive property hold for the set of objects with relevant number = 0.

I cannot take sole credit for being the first to answer this though.